Docker-compose to use dockerfile that access external files
I have a docker-compose that when is mounting ac image, the dockerfile of this image needs to go up 2 directories because this repo uses the directory type.  So given this, how can I make my docker file to access this external directory without changing the code  path usage in this repo?
This is an example of the directory structure:
Documents:
-.env
-docker-compose.yml
-ac
-dc
-type
So I have this docker-compose:
version: '3.8'
services:
  ac:
    build: ./ac
    container_name: ac
    ports:
      - "4112:4112"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .env
        target: /app/.env
  dc:
    build: ./dc
    container_name: dc
    ports:
      - "2001:2001"

This is the dockerfile for the ac repo:
FROM python:3.11-bullseye

# Set the working directory inside the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create directories
COPY ../type/example/dog ./type/example/dog

# Copy the requirements file first to leverage Docker cache
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of your application code into the container
COPY . .

# Command to run the Uvicorn server
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4112"]

So my issue is that when I do the docker-compose the ac repo doesn't access the directory:/type/example/dog, why is that?

So I need to copy the files directoy inside the docker image?

Dockerfiles can't go outside the build context. To access files higher in the directory tree, you need to set the context so the files you need are included in the context.
For your ac image, you'd change your compose file to
  ac:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./ac/Dockerfile
    container_name: ac
    ports:
      - "4112:4112"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .env
        target: /app/.env

and your Dockerfile to
FROM python:3.11-bullseye

# Set the working directory inside the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Create directories
COPY type/example/dog ./type/example/dog

# Copy the requirements file first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ac/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of your application code into the container
COPY ac/. .

# Command to run the Uvicorn server
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "4112"]

The Dockerfile is untested, so you might have to tweak it. I hope you get the gist of the changes needed.

thank you @Hans but I have another doubt, the code inside ac repo is using the env file with the path ../.env, so in this case I have to alter this path right?

No. The build context is only used at build time. The .env file is mounted at run-time and is not using the build context. So it should be fine the way it is.

and the files path on the code, should I alter them to be this:./type/example/dog? instead of .../type/example/dog?

You should only change the host paths in your COPY statements. You had COPY ../type/example/dog ./type/example/dog which creates /app/type/example/dog in the image. After the change you'll have COPY type/example/dog ./type/example/dog which also creates /app/type/example/dog. So things inside the image will be the same as before.
